# Ruby- Rspec not running tests on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am running ruby on rails in my windows 8 machine.I was following a tutorial to download the gems rspec and capybara for testing purposes. When I started writing my tests and using the terminal to rub my file create_spec.rb it just keeps coming up with a bunch of errors. I dont understand what I am doing wrong :

```
Directory of C:\Sites\projects\odot\spec\features\todo_lists

02/05/2015  15:46    <DIR>          .
02/05/2015  15:46    <DIR>          ..
05/12/2013  14:53             1,479 create_spec.rb
           1 File(s)          1,479 bytes
           2 Dir(s)   3,605,815,296 bytes free

C:\Sites\projects\odot\spec\features\todo_lists>rspec create_spec.rb
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:
in `require': cannot load such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
`require'
    from C:/Sites/projects/odot/spec/features/todo_lists/create_spec.rb:1:in
 `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/cor
e/configuration.rb:1065:in `load'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/cor
e/configuration.rb:1065:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/cor
e/configuration.rb:1065:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/cor
e/configuration.rb:1065:in `load_spec_files'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/cor
e/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/cor
e/runner.rb:103:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/cor
e/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

Comment: Have you created the proper spec_helper.rb or rails_helper.rb? You usually have to require this at the top of your spec-file.

Comment: Try changing directories to `C:\Sites\projects\odot`  and run `rspec spec` instead.

Comment: I have the file spec_helper.rb. Still not working. When I run rspec spec it says i need to install a gem rspec-spec. i runned the command but comes up with active support dependencies problem. @papirtiger

Comment: Have you installed rspec correctly with the following command- rails generate rspec:install. If so are you definitely running rspec from the root of your directory? Finally which version of Rspec are you using?